# Set Chrome to go to last used tab after tab is closed

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

I'm an ex Opera user so, simply because of how I am used to certain behaviors, I wanna create them in chrome.
For instance: All new tabs should open at the end of all tabs, not next to the current. There is an extension for that, so its all working fine.
Now, in Opera it was like, when you close any tab the focus goes to the tab that you last used/looked at before this one. In Chrome it just shows you the one in front of that tab, order wise.
Is there any way to change that ?

Example situation: Browsing News page, opening 4 new news items in new tabs, looking at one, closing it, it should bring me back to the news list that I looked at before that. But currently it would just bring me to any of those other items, which ever is in row.

Comment: Try Vivaldi. Runs on Chromium also.

Comment: This issue is from 2014, and actually by now I am indeed using Vivaldi. I would also recommend it to everyone. Seems like non google chromium browser are getting quite the traction, like Brave as well.

Comment: I know the issue is old but since other search for this all the time, it's quite evergreen.

Answer (score 10):

[FLST Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flst-chrome/ajnianifcggmdojhnmjichjmnjpplcha/details)(Focus Last Selected Tab) seems to do both of what you're asking.

Feature Set:

> - Natural Tab Ordering :: when the selected-tab is closed, Focus goes to the Last-Selected-Tab
> - Multiple Window Support :: private tab ordering is maintained for each window
> - Tab Migration :: tabs are also tracked when dragged between windows
> - Options Page :: right-click the extension icon and select Options
> - (Option) Tab-flipping :: flips the current and last tab
> - (Option) New Tabs :: switch to the new tab when created
> - (Option) Tab Location :: place new tabs on the far-right

PS. I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the extension mentioned in the answer above and it didn't work for me. It doesn't appear to have that option anymore.

Posting a few alternatives in case someone else wonders here:

[Tab Position Customizer 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-customizer-2/jglbflnkbgbklegdblkohbbbheeeklej) - Personally tested and it works as described.

[Tab Position Options](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-options/fjccjnfkdkdmjohojoggodkigkjkkjhl) - Personally tested and it works as described.

Bonus note about one I tried that **didn't work**:

[TabsPlus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabsplus/nikomkkhhpfoeamojhhgpfkpkdlfhfii) - There seems to be a bug where the go to last active tab doesn't work if you have multiple windows opened. Since the app hasn't been updated since 2013, I doubt it'll ever work again.